# add redirect in nginx from `url.org//` to `url.org`

Tags: nginx

I have a request from our SEO consultant to add a redirect from `url.org//` to `url.org`. I have tried some articles here, but with not much luck:

https://serverfault.com/questions/597302/removing-the-trailing-slash-from-a-url-with-nginx

I also tried this in my `sites-enabled/url.conf` file:

```
location ~* \/\/$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/;
}
```

Pardon my nginx ignorance in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot detect `//` with a `location` rule, as the URI has already been normalized, and multiple occurrences of consecutive `/`s have been folded into a single `/`. You will need to use the original URI which is represented by the `$request_uri` variable.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ (.*/)/$) { return 301 $1; }
```

Comment: Worked as expected.  Thank you.